# Why does a breakpoint in CompletableFuture stops execution in Main thread as well?

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, parallel-processing, completable-future

I am trying a simple code snippet to check if CompletableFuture does work in separate thread.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            // method call or code to be asynch.
            new Worker().work();
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("Main : " + i);
        }
    }

    private static class Worker {
        public void work() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println("Worker : " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seemingly, it looks like they are working in parallel by console output

```
Worker : 0
Main : 0
Worker : 1
Main : 1
Worker : 2
Main : 2
Worker : 3
Main : 3
Worker : 4
Main : 4
Worker : 5
Main : 5
Worker : 6
Main : 6
Worker : 7
Main : 7
Worker : 8
```

and more lines.

The confusion arises as I put a breakpoint in `work()` method. Ideally as soon as line in `work()` is hit, execution in CompletableFuture threads stop and mean while `main()` thread should keep executing and print all console out puts. But in reality execution in both threads stops and nothing prints.

Is it because of very nature of

1. Java?
2. IntelliJ?
3. Processor?
4. OS?

I am using a processor `2.2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7` on a Macbook Pro.

Why is it so?

Comment: Yes it did. I have marked the answer accepted.

Comment: In that case you can also accept the duplicate proposal, as it helps other people find the best answers 

Comment: @DidierL Do you want me to mark it duplicate?

Comment: @DidierL I agree that both the questions have same solution. But different questions, it will help people who doesn't even know if the issue is with the language, OS, or IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because that is the behavior of IntelliJ. If you have a breakpoint, right-click on it and it shows the following popup:

[image]

Under `Suspend`, you'll see that all threads are halted if you reach that breakpoint. You also have the option to only stop the current thread.